# Sending and receiving via AJAX | PhoneGap App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap application with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 & jQuery 2.0.3. I have a login form with a username and a password. There is a PHP which accepts the POSTed variables and returns JSON encoded data to allow the login process to proceed.

I use the following JavaScript for the ajax login.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
function onDeviceReady() {
    $(function () {
        $("#login_form").submit(function() {
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",               
                data: postData,
                url: "url of PHP file that takes in credentials and sends back json encoded response",              
                success: function(data){    
                    var login_data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (login_data.success == "go") {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {transition:"slide", changeHash:false});                  
                    } else if (login_data.success == "no go") {
                        navigator.notification.alert("Email Not Found. Please Register.", function(){}, "Alert", "OK");
                    } else {    
                        navigator.notification.alert("Login Failed. Please Try Again.", function(){}, "Alert", "OK");       
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    navigator.notification.alert(err.Message, function(){}, "Alert", "OK");
                }
            });         
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

I'm having an issue when more than one device is connected via the same wifi router. One or the other device will connect and the other will stall and occasionally give the AJAX failed message.

Searching around and asking colleagues I'm whittling down reasons why this is failing. The code works...in isolation. And the code works when two devices are used while connected to two different wifi routers.

At this point my best guess is that because each device is sending out near identical info to the router it goes and returns with the response, but doesn't know which device to return the responses to as they are not individually tagged (perhaps with their individual mac addresses or assigned IP numbers - don't laugh too hard, I'm a networking noob).

Any ideas on what might cause this fail and ways I can go about testing and fixing it?

Comment: First if you are expecting a response in JSON format add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call. As far as fixing the blocking problem it sounds to me that your configuration on the server accepts only one call at a time. Usually servers create "children" processes for every request. You can look at it as 20 requests results in 20 simultaneous connections. If the request nr is higher than the amount of concurrent requests allowed by your server, the server will refuse the connection. Maybe your server only allows one connection per IP (wifi IP)

Comment: From what you are saying this is clearly a network configuration issue and not related to JQuery, JQuery Mobile or Cordova. Have you tried repeating the process with 2 devices on the same network but different from the one you normally use. This would identify if this was purely an issue with one specific network config.

Comment: Corresponded with Web Host and in non-fluent English they told me that they upped the simultaneous connections from 20 to 40. I tested it like they asked, but knew from the outset that it wouldn't work. Telling them again what my problem is they suggested it was my own firewall. Any ideas on how to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an unknown issue with the Web Host provider. Despite more than a dozen detailed requests for what on their side was blocking things I was always referred to how my own equipment or own code was at fault.

Set myself up a VPS and presto change-o I have a working system with no modifications to the code or the equipment.

TIL I don't like people who cover up their incompetency by blaming others.